# Single Page loader PDF reader in PHP / Ruby / .NET

Tags: pdf-reader

I've very large sized PDF files. I want a PDF reader (PHP / Ruby / .NET) that does not load the whole file but just the page so that the response time gets better.

There are many PHP and .NET PDF readers but I'm not sure if they just load a page or load the whole file at once.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: if you are not sure why don't you try one of them, like a .NET one in a windows forms test application and see how it works? or how would it work if you put the web browser control in a windows forms and pass the pdf document? if it hosts the standard Acrobat Reader, I would expect that to read only the current page then use load on demand on scrolling.

Comment: I need a pdf reader that also offer an API so I can ask him (programmatically) to load n page and it does without loading the whole file.